# How can I change jasper report parameter font using java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I create jtextarea and I load system all font styles to the jcombobox. Then I have changed font style of jtextarea selecting jcombobox font styles. It's worked good. And I create jasper report to print jtextarea values. Then report will print, But report didn't get I used font style. I just need print report with I selected font style.

here my javacode:

```
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.
                    getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            String[] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
            System.out.println(fonts[1]);

            for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
                jComboBox1.addItem(fonts[i]);
            }

            //   jComboBox1.addItem(fonts);

        }
    });
```

Print Button Code:

```
             try {



            String reportSource = "C:/Users/Sajana/Documents/Simon Report/ltr_a4.jrxml";

            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();


         params.put("ltr", jTextArea1.getText());



             JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, newJREmptyDataSource());                                                             
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
```

If anyone knows to do this,Please help me!